# Please guide me about my Yii2 code about RESTFul authentication by token

Tags: rest, authentication, yii2

I have been look around google whole day and still not getting idea how to achieve RESTFul httpBasicAuth by using token.

First, I would like to ask can i using RESTFul HttpBasicAuth without Https ?

Then, below is my code to try to do Yii2 RESTFul HttpBasicAuth authenticaton, hope someone can spend some time review on my code and guide me what wrong on my code.

First this is my yii2 config setting about User Application component:

```
'user' => ['identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
'enableAutoLogin' => false
],
```

then below is snippet of my common\models\Users IdentityClass

namespace common\models;

```
use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use app\models\Ostoken;
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        /* Compulsory for RESTFul*/
        //         die("trying...");
        //         throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');

        file_put_contents("/var/www/html/y2api/logs/RESTFul_login_".date("Y-m-d"), date("H:i:s").":".$token."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

        $apiUser = Ostoken::find()
        ->where(['token' => $token])
        ->one();

        return static::findOne(['username' => $apiUser->username]);
    }
}
```

then I try to call the restful URL by `http://192.168.33.10/api/Banktransactions?access-token=xxxxxxxx`

then i get following error in json format :

```
{
    "name": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Your request was made with invalid credentials.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 401,
    "type": "yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"
}
```

as you can see I put a file_put_contents in `findIdentityByAccessToken` but it never execute.

Answer (score 1):

First question:

> First, I would like to ask can i using RESTFul HttpBasicAuth without Https ?

Answer: You can, but:

> Since an access token can be used to uniquely identify and authenticate a user, API requests should always be sent via HTTPS to prevent man-in-the-middle (MitM) attacks. (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication#authentication)

Second...question?:

I'm 100% sure this is because CORS.
Check out this:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-cors

Ever tried to reach the url through localhost? If so and it worked then you need to set up a CORS filter to be able to make a request to your server.